# Can I use my NZ restricted drivers license in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license, new-zealand

Can I drive in the UK with my restricted NZ license?

I have my EEA FP and am in the application process of getting my residency. I have not been here 185 days yet.

Thanks for the help
Sammy Jay Dawson

Comment: Related question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20174/driving-in-uk-on-a-non-uk-eu-licence?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 1):

No, according to gov.uk website you are able to drive in the UK only if you have a full driving licence from another country, for a limited period of time.

If you want to check the details, follow the link below:
https://www.gov.uk/driving-nongb-licence

If I were you, I would apply for a UK provisional licence ASAP.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Actually it does, eg for a visitor from a designated country (of which NZ is one) “You can drive any type of small vehicle (for example cars or motorcycles) listed on your full and valid licence for 12 months from when you last entered Great Britain (GB)”. Similar for a resident, with the 12 months’ restriction starting from date of residency